# the image get zoomed out and quality is poor when taking from vedio camera using javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, html5-canvas, getusermedia, mediapipe

I have created a web application that uses the mediaPipe API. With this APP i use the rear camera to detect a person's face and click the picture.

Once the picture is clicked i get the MediaPipe api resultimage object that i write on Canvas. It works well expect the image gets Zoom out on the canvas and the quality of the image is also poor.

I am adding sample code below. Your help would be much appreciated.

below is the code to open the video

```
const videoHeight = 1080;
const videoWidth = 1920
const mode = 'environment';
const camera = new Camera(videoRef.current, {
    onFrame: async () => {
        await faceDetection.send({ image: videoRef.current });
    },
    facingMode: {
        exact: mode
    },
    width: {
        min: videoWidth
    },
    height: {
        min: videoHeight
    }
});
camera.start();
```

code to draw the image on the canvas

```
const getDimensions = (result) => {
    var maxWidth = videoRef.current.clientWidth; // Max width for the image
    var maxHeight = videoRef.current.clientHeight;    // Max height for the image

    var ratio = 0;  // Used for aspect ratio
    var width = result.image.width;    // Current image width
    var height = result.image.height;  // Current image height

    // Check if the current width is larger than the max
    if (width > maxWidth) {
        ratio = maxWidth / width;   // get ratio for scaling image
        height = height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
        width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
    }

    // Check if current height is larger than max
    if (height > maxHeight) {
        ratio = maxHeight / height; // get ratio for scaling image
        width = width * ratio;    // Reset width to match scaled image
        height = height * ratio;    // Reset height to match scaled image
    }
    return { width: width, height: height }
}




const canvasElement = canvasImgRef.current;
const clientDims = getDimensions(result);  // result is the mediaPipe result
canvasElement.width = clientDims.width;
canvasElement.height = clientDims.height;
let canvasCtx = canvasElement.getContext('2d');
canvasCtx.save();
canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, clientDims.width, clientDims.height);
canvasCtx.drawImage(result.image, 0, 0, clientDims.width, clientDims.height); // resul.image is the mediaPipe image

if (result.detections.length > 0) {
    result.detections.forEach(detection => {
        drawRectangle(canvasCtx, detection.boundingBox, { color: 'black', lineWidth: 2, fillColor: 'black' });
    })
}
canvasCtx.restore();
```

it would be great help me if anyone let me know how i can control the zoom of the image and improve the quality.

i tried by changing the height, width constraint, changing the aspect ratio etc...

Comment: I wonder if this happen on Native API call ? or it is an issue related to using the video & camera in JS only

Comment: thanks for your responce. the issue related to using vedio camera in JS only. there is no Native API call

Answer (score 0):

1. It is not very clear from your code what you are using to work with the camera. If you are using `@mediapipe/camera_utils` then you using incorrect parameters because according to the interface it should be

```
facingMode?: 'user'|'environment';
width?: number;
height?: number;
```

2. Do you need to draw on canvas some specific frame from the video stream that the function `faceDetection` receives? if so, look at this link https://face-detection-codemichael81.netlify.app/ I made an example using MediaPipe that displays video on the canvas and occupies the entire screen, if this is what you need, then you also need to correctly calculate the width and height and offset when the window sizes have different proportions from the image

```
    function (output, canvasCtx, img) {
        output.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        output.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    
        const heightMargin =
          Math.max((img.width / img.height) * output.height - output.width, 0) / 2;
        const widthMargin =
          Math.max((img.height / img.width) * output.width - output.height, 0) / 2;
    
        canvasCtx.drawImage(
          img,
          0,
          0,
          Math.trunc(output.width + 2 * heightMargin),
          Math.trunc(output.height + 2 * widthMargin)
        );
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello Michael thanks for your help. i have changed the parameter and calculate the image dimension as per your suggestion but the image is still getting zoomed and the quality of the image is still very poor.below is the modified code

```
        const videoHeight = 1080;
            const videoWidth = 1920
            const camera = new Camera(videoRef.current, {
                        onFrame: async () => {
                            await faceDetection.send({ image: videoRef.current });
                        },
                        facingMode:  'environment',
                        width: videoWidth,
                        height: videoHeight
            });
            camera.start();
            
            const getDimensions = (result) => {
                var maxWidth = videoRef.current.clientWidth; // Max width for the image
                var maxHeight = videoRef.current.clientHeight;    // Max height for the image
        
                // var ratio = 0;  // Used for aspect ratio
                var width = result.image.width;    // Current image width
                var height = result.image.height;  // Current image height
        
                const heightMargin = Math.max((width / height) * maxHeight - maxWidth, 0) / 2;
                const widthMargin = Math.max((height / width) * maxWidth - maxHeight, 0) / 2;
                width = Math.trunc(maxWidth + 2 * heightMargin);
                height =  Math.trunc(maxHeight + 2 * widthMargin);
                return { width: width, height: height }
            }
const drawPicture = () => {
            if (result) {
                const canvasElement = canvasImgRef.current;
                const clientDims = getDimensions(result);
                canvasElement.width = clientDims.width;
                canvasElement.height = clientDims.height;
                let canvasCtx = canvasElement.getContext('2d');
                canvasCtx.save();
                canvasCtx.clearRect(0, 0, clientDims.width, clientDims.height);
                canvasCtx.drawImage(result.image, 0, 0, clientDims.width, clientDims.height);
                if (result.detections.length > 0) {
                    result.detections.forEach(detection => {
                        drawRectangle(canvasCtx, detection.boundingBox, { color: 'black', lineWidth: 2, fillColor: 'black' });
                    })
                }
                canvasCtx.restore();
            }
        }
```

[this is the image genrated from the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fWAIY.png)

Answer (score 0):

I have updated the link to example [https://face-detection-codemichael81.netlify.app](https://face-detection-codemichael81.netlify.app/), try to take a photo using my link and click on the screen when you need to generate an image, this will open a new tab with the result.
[Image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u4OtC.jpg)

If it works as you need, then I got this result using to generate a photo directly a screenshot from the video and draw on it again the result of detection but not canvas which is obtained as a result of face detection. To make it easier to work with video and take a screenshot of a video, you can use, for example this library https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-webcam, instead of html video

Comment: I work with Kiran, the link is stuck in "loading..." can you verify ? thx

Comment: @user1516770 link works, please check camera permissions if you have allowed it for this link/page, maybe this is the reason why it is stuck in "loading..."

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi,
I tried to implement your suggestion by taking snapshot from video instead of the canvas but still it is not resolving the issue.

Even i tried your example link and took the image and the size of the image is changed from what it shown before taking the screenshot. you can see that it is like doing a zoom or change the angle of the picture.

Could you share github link of your example repo I want to check image quality and size after uploading it to cloud?

Comment: @user1516770 https://codepen.io/codemichael81/pen/WNgdGQp , Hi! for some reason cannot access the camera in codepen, you can run this locally and try

Comment: I tried your solution by creating a local project and fixed the camera on browser but when i tested with latest Android version phone (any Samsung ones for example)  it is throwing the error "
notReadableError: Could not start video source" do you have any idea? Thx a lot

Comment: @user1516770 check if the camera is being used by another application

Comment: hello @MichaelF Thanks for your help. With your solution the quality of the image is much bettter but the image is still getting zoom out on android's browers.